# Is there an appropriate spot in Stack Exchange for code challenge invite?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there an appropriate spot in Stack Exchange to post an invitation to a code challenge? I've produced a code challenge for my JavaScript user group. It deals with a issue created by Chrome's problematic implementation of Date.parse(), to which I could find no satisfying answer. I've created a GitHub repository with a coding environment for my group to workout the challenge, and I would like to invite the larger JavaScript developer community to consider the question.

The challenge presents a problem for which there is not an obvious perfect answer. It does involve writing code, because it's a search for a better parsing algorithm for what is a common and critical task in every JavaScript developer's daily routine: determining if a string represents a parsable date.

Comment: Is it an actual question, or a request to write code?

Comment: Nope there isn't. Stack Exchange isn't a social network.

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara It presents a problem for which there is not an obvious perfect answer.  It does involve writing code, because it's a search for a better parsing algorithm for what is a common and critical task in every JS developers daily routine: determining if a string represents a parseable date

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange is a Q&A site. If a post is not a question which can reasonably be answered in a Q&A format, there really isn't a Stack Exchange site to post it to.

That being said, I suppose you could advertise it with [Stack Overflow ads](https://stackoverflow.com/help/advertising).

Comment: I appreciate the answer, Alexander.  Happy coding!

Comment: What about PPCG, Code Review, Software Recs, Hardware Recs, etc.?  They are sites that are not asking for the one possible answer.  I can't think of an appropriate site for the OP, but I don't think it necessarily goes against Stack Exchange in general.

Comment: @zondo I didn't say "one possible answer", many questions have multiple answers, just that questions that don't fit the Q&A format don't fit.

Comment: The question is "What is the best parsing algorithm for ...."  There can be multiple opinions, multiple factors, but so are there on Code Review, Software and Hardware Recs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's that problem with Chrome's implementation.

But it sounds like you could ask a question

- Explaining what exactly you want to achieve
- Including your attempt with `Date.parse()`
- Explaining why it didn't work as you expected on Chrome

To attract more attention, you can [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). This will be like an invitation:

> The bountied question will appear with a special indicator in all
>   question lists, and it will also be visible on the [homepage Featured
>   tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) for 7 days.

Then people will be able to post answers with different approaches to the problem. The community will vote, and you can accept whichever answer you found more useful.